# How do I extract specific pieces of text in a website with soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making Japanese flashcards by scraping the this [website](https://jpdb.io/search?q=%E7%A6%8F+%23kanji&lang=english#a)

My plan is to format it in a text file with the kanji, its 3 word examples, the hirigana reading on top of each of the words, and the english translation below it.

I want it to look like this:

```
kanji {word1},{hirigana},{english translation}
{word2},{hirigana},{english translation}
{word3},{hirigana},{english translation}
```

**Example**:

福 祝福 祝福,しゅくふ,blessing 
幸福,こうふく,happiness; well-being; joy; welfare; blessedness 
裕福,ゆうふく,wealthy; rich; affluent; well-off

---

So far I am trying just with the website I mentioned and eventually loop it for a list of kanji character I have. However I am not sure how to extract the text [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYnrW.png) from [the website](https://jpdb.io/search?q=%E7%A6%8F+%23kanji&lang=english#a)

I know soup can be used however I dont know what to put in the function to get the text I want.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

word1_list = []
word2_list = []
word3_list = []

kanji = '福'
url = f'https://jpdb.io/search?q={kanji}+%23kanji&lang=english#a'
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get(url)

# // uncertain what I should put here
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, 'html.parser')
words = soup.select('div.jp')  # // uncertain what I should put here
word1_list.append(words)  # // I want to try putting the data I want here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of getting the information you're after:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://jpdb.io/search?q=%E7%A6%8F+%23kanji&lang=english#a'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
soup = bs(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
translation = soup.select_one('h6:-soup-contains("Keyword")').find_next('div').get_text(strip=True)
print(translation)

big_list = []
japanese_texts = soup.select('div[class="jp"]')
for j in japanese_texts:
    japanese_text = j.get_text(strip=True)
    translation = j.find_next_sibling('div').get_text(strip=True)
    big_list.append((japanese_text, translation))

df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['Japanese', 'English'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
good fortune
Japanese    English
0   ç¥ç¦  blessing
1   å¹¸ç¦  happiness; well-being; joy; welfare; bless...
2   è£ç¦  wealthy; rich; affluent; well-off
3   æãããã¨ãããã¦æããããã¨ã...   To love and to be loved is the greatest happin...
4   å½¼ã¯å¹¸ç¦ã§ããããã ã   He seems happy.
5   å¹¸ç¦ãªèãããã°ãã¾ãä¸å¹¸ãªèã...   Some are happy; others unhappy.
```

BeautifulSoup documentation can be found [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Also, try to avoid using deprecated packages: requests-html was last released on Feb 17, 2019, so it's pretty much unmaintained.